# GIF como fondo de pantalla JFrame Java

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Estoy intentando colocar un **GIF** como fondo de pantalla, el problema es que el **GIF** no me ocupa toda la pantalla. ¿Como puedo arreglarlo para que el **GIF** ocupe toda la pantalla de forma que aunque se cambie el tamaño de la ventana este siga ocupando todo?

Este es mi código:

```
public class ViewInicio extends JFrame {

    private JLabel fondo;

    public ViewInicio() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(1500,900);
        setTitle("View Inicio");
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
        setIconImage(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resources/icon.png")).getImage());
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        fondo = new JLabel();
        fondo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/hundirlaflotilla/resources/fondo.gif")));
        getContentPane().add(fondo);

        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

para que el tamaño de la imagen de fondo se modifique 
adecuandose al de la ventana, debes asignar la imagen de fondo con
la escala adecuada en el evento que controla el cambio de tamaño del
JFrame, seria asi:

```
addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ev) {
        Image imgFondo=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imagenes/fondo.gif")).getImage();
        fondo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(imgFondo.getScaledInstance(ev.getComponent().getWidth(), ev.getComponent().getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT)));
    }
});
```

Espero te haya sido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta las dimensiones de la imagen `GIF`, y la de tu Pane en el **`Jframe`**.
Al colocar la imagen como fondo busca la propiedad `MAXIMUN SIZE`